# Using private variable in class

Tags: c++, class, variables, crash

I'm running into an irritating problem where my program keeps crashing if I try to reference a private variable that I have created in one of my classes. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Here is the class that calls the class that crashes:

```
#include <stack>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include "schemeList.cpp"

using namespace std;

class dataLog
{
public:
stack<string> commands;
set<string> domain;
processor tokens;
int nextToken;
schemeList * s;
dataLog(stack<string> s, ofstream * out, processor p, int location)
{
    commands = s;
    tokens = p;
    nextToken = location;
    commands.push("<Query List>");
    commands.push(":");
    commands.push("Queries");
    commands.push("<Rule List>");
    commands.push(":");
    commands.push("Rules");
    commands.push("<Fact List>");
    commands.push(":");
    commands.push("Facts");
    commands.push("<Scheme List>");
    commands.push(":");
    commands.push("Schemes");
    checkNext();
}

void checkNext()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.tags.size(); i++)
    {
        if(commands.top().compare(tokens.tags[i].getName())!=0)
        {
            if(commands.top().find("<")==0)
            {
                if(commands.top().compare("<Scheme List>")==0)
                {
                    int output = (*s).process(i, tokens, domain);                       string hi = (*s).toString();

                }
            }
        }
        commands.pop();
    }

}
};
```

This class creates an object of my SchemeList class, which is written out as follows:

```
#include "schemes.cpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class schemeList
{
private:
string success;

public:
int process(int number, processor p, set<string> domain)
{
    success = "HELLO";
    return 13;
}

string toString()
{
    return success;
}

};
```

As soon as I get to line 15 `success = "HELLO";`, the program crashes with the message

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00E48B66 in lab2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading   
 location 0xCCCCCCE4.
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Comment: Your problem is not related to accessing a private data member. How do you initialize the ``schemeList*`` data member of ``dataLog``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the variable `schemeList * dataLog::s` is never initialized, so accessing it is undefined behavior, which leads to the crash. Most likely calling process on a dangling pointer and attempting to write into some memory you don't own.

Second, don't `#include "schemeList.cpp"`. You're not supposed to include `cpp` files. Rather, separate declarations & implementations and include a header.

Comment: Excellent, that was it exactly. Thank you so much, I just had to change it from being a pointer. Now it reads "schemeList s;".

Comment: @user1693804 a lot better to not use pointers when you don't have to, great.

Answer (score 1):

You have not initialized `dataLog::s`. When you call `(*s).process(i, tokens, domain)`, you get undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're apparently including source code files in headers. This will likely break the one definition rule and go horribly wrong.

Secondly, 's' is not a very good name for a class member. It makes it almost impossible to find uses of it.

Thirdly, I can see nowhere in your code that initialises s. I can see where it gets referenced OK, but as it hasn't been initialised, the effect of dereferencing is undefined, and with luck will merely crash your program, which looks like what is happening.